# Is it correct using "even" and "still" together?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct using even & still in one statement?

eg:

> "even after a warning, he is still doing the same"

I think either is redundant, isn't it?

Comment: It may be redundant. But, it is certainly common usage.

Comment: They are not being redundant with each other. Each word ("even" and "still") is doing its own thing where it is located at -- it has a purpose that it is fulfilling where the other word has no influence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've posted it in comments and gotten enough up votes to post it as answer.

Yes, it does sound slightly redundant.  But, it is certainly common usage.  And, definitely not incorrect.

I believe it adds emphasis.

Consider:

> After a warning, he is still doing the same."

This guy got warned, and he is still doing it.

vs.

> Even after a warning, he is still doing the same."

Despite being warned, he is still at it.

The meanings are extremely similar, but the second one adds a sense of exasperation to the statement.  Perhaps exasperation is too strong of a word, but I cannot think of a better one.  (I'm very open to suggestions for a better one!)

Answer (score 3):

It is grammatically correct but I find it more refined to use continues instead of still.

For example,

> Even after the warning, he is still cheating on the test.

vs.

> Even after the warning, he continues to cheat on the test.

I find the second to be more appealing but it is all up to opinion.

Comment: It's not quite all "up to opinion" but both expressions are possible. I think the second is better as "even after the warning, he continues to cheat on tests" (i.e. an action that keeps happening in different instances) vs. the former expressing that he does not heed the warning now.

Answer (score 0):

It is better "After the warning, he is still cheating on the test." I do believe the two words are a redundancy. "Brevity is the soul of wit." Stephen King calls it "killing your babies," meaning taking out your unneccesary words. I believe abbreviating a sentence, without making it choppy, can add impact in writing.

Comment: I don't like the sound of what results after dropping either of the _tautologues?_  And Orwell outranks King.